# Unable to view ls in the overflow css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing the problem of displaying the ls elements which is in a div > ul with overflow css. This is a vertical list with drop-down list. I am using a 'overflow:scroll' on the vertical list. Now if there is no overflow in the code, it just works fine. But with the overflow, the dropdown menu is not being shown.

Here is the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/aryasobn/mpb6h831/

Here is the css and html code.

```
<style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
            #map {
              height: 100%;
            }
            /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
            html, body {
              height: 100%;
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
            }

            .dropdown-submenu{position:relative;}
            .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{top:0;left:100%;margin-top:-6px;margin-left:-1px;-webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;}
            .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu{display:block;}
            .dropdown-submenu>a:after{display:block;content:" ";float:right;width:0;height:0;border-color:transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;border-left-color:#cccccc;margin-top:5px;margin-right:-10px;}
            .dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after{border-left-color:#ffffff;}
            .dropdown-submenu{float:none;}
            .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{left:-100%;margin-right:10px;-webkit-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;-moz-border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;border-radius:6px 0 6px 6px;}

            .sidebar{
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 0px;
                  right:0px;
                  text-align: center;
                  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
                  line-height: 30px;
                  padding-left: 10px;
                  z-index: 10;
                  float:right;
                  margin-right:20px;
                  height: 700px;
                  overflow: scroll;
            }

            .sidebar ul{
                z-index:25;
            }

            #mainist li{
                z-index:50;
            }
    </style>
    <div id="floating-panel" class="sidebar">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: block; position: static;" id="mainlist">
          <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Set1</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="usa">
                    <li><a href="#">Reebok</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Set1</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="canada">
                    <li><a href="#">Reebok</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Can some one help me with this.

Here is an image how it is currently looking:[image]

Thanks all.

Comment: I can't see `overflow:scroll` property in your code and still your code isn't working. Please clarify that issue is with overflow or without ?

Comment: I checked that on removing `overflow-x:auto` and `overflow-y: auto` drop down works well. So what is the issue ? What you trying to implement using overflow?

Comment: I have a lot of data. That is why I need overflow.

Comment: I should have overflow in order to have scroll bar.

Comment: @Nimish There is overflow in there. Even if change the overflow to scroll or auto it os not working. But I will be changing to scroll as per your suggestion so that it will be on par with question.

Comment: So apply scroll to drop down not `.sidebar`

Answer (score 0):

Apply overflow scroll to inner `ul` not on `.sidebar`. Check Snippet. If you want another thing, please tell and I will modify it.

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #cccccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 700px;
}

.sidebar ul {
  z-index: 25;
}

.abc {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#mainist li {
  z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="floating-panel" class="sidebar">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: block; position: static;" id="mainlist">
      <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Set1</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu abc" id="usa">
          <li><a href="#">Reebok</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reebok</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reebok</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reebok</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#">Set1</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu abc" id="canada">
          <li><a href="#">Reebok</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried your code and worked fine. But that is not what I am asking right now. Imagine if we have a lot of data in the parent list and we need a scroll bar on that. https://jsfiddle.net/aryasobn/3z8mq4k3/ Here is a fiddle code. Please check. I appreciate the help.